# Creating object with reference to Interface

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

A reference variable can be declared as a class type or an interface type.If the variable is declared as an interface type, it can reference any object of any class that implements the interface.

Based on the above statement I have made a code on understanding. As said above **declared as an interface type, it can reference any object of any class that implements the interface**.

But in my code is displaying `displayName()` method undefined at `objParent.displayName()`:

```java
public class OverridenClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printable objParent = new Parent();
        objParent.sysout();
        objParent.displayName();
    }
}

interface Printable {
    void sysout();
}

class Parent implements Printable {
    public void displayName() {
        System.out.println("This is Parent Name");
    }

    public void sysout() {
        System.out.println("I am Printable Interfacein Parent Class");
    }
}
```

I am sure I have understood the wrong way. Can someone explain the same?

Comment: You can only access the methods defined on the interface by which reference has been created. so in your case only ```sysout()``` method is called successfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But in my code is displaying displayName()method undefined.

Right, because `displayName` is not defined in the `Printable` interface. You can only access the methods defined on the interface through a variable declared as having that interface, even if the concrete class has additional methods. That's why you can call `sysout`, but not `displayName`.

The reason for this is more apparent if you consider an example like this:

```java
class Bar {
    public static void foo(Printable p) {
        p.sysout();
        p.displayName();
    }
}

class Test {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Bar.foo(new Parent());
    }
}
```

The code in `foo` **must not** rely on anything other than what is featured in the `Printable` interface, as we have no idea at compile-time what the concrete class may be.

The point of interfaces is to define the characteristics that are available to the code using only an interface reference, without regard to the concrete class being used.

Comment: But in kathy bates its like If the variable is declared as an interface type, it can reference any object of any class that implements the interface.What do they exactly mean by any object of any class that implements the interface

Comment: By that they mean it can hold any object of which implements that interface, but to access that additional methods which is defined in the implementor you need to type-cast it. See my answer

Comment: @JavaBeginner: It *can* reference any object implementing the interface, but it can only *use* features of that object that are defined by the interface. This is the whole point of having an interface reference: Avoiding coupling to any specific concrete class.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - You mean like with out Casting

Comment: @JavaBeginner: Right, but if you have to resort to casting, the odds are your code needs to be refactored. The point of using an interface is to code to the interface and not rely on features of the concrete class. If you need to use the features of the concrete class, declare your variable using that class, not the interface.

Answer (score 4):

The `displayName()` method is displayed as undefined because `objParent` declared as type `Printable` and the interface does not have such method. To be able to use method `displayName()`, you can declare it in interface `Printable`:

```java
interface Printable {
    void sysout();
    void displayName();
}
```

Or cast `objParent` to type `Parent` first before calling method `displayName()`:

```java
Printable objParent = new Parent();
objParent = (Parent) objParent;
objParent.displayName();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to type cast it to get the access to the `Parent` methods

```
((Parent)objParent).displayName();
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply Eclipse suggested the same

Comment: Welcome :) Hope that helps

Comment: @JavaBeginner: There is **no** point to doing this. You may as well simply declare `objParent` as a `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't care about run-time. as far as the compiler is concerned, it checks if the reference type has a method called display in your interface type.

> methods declared in your sub-class or implementing class are not part
>   of your super class/interface. thus you cannot invoke those methods
>   which are declared in sub-class with super class/interface reference
>   type.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are basically another way of - breaking the rules of single inheritance.

By using interfaces, a child class can, both inherit it's parents methods and be forced to implement it's interface methods. Resulting in an easy to extend and maintain inheritance tree etc.

The catch however is, when the child is referenced under the parent, you only have access to the parent methods. To access the interface methods, you will need to cast or create the child under the interface reference type.

Interfaces also allow the collection of multiple classes of different families to be collected under the interface type. To what benefit I am yet to discover.

In my opinion, it is pointless since I still cannot achieve fully blown polymorphism anyways - by just using the parent reference type and still have access to the interface implementations.

Answer (score 0):

wherever the method signature reside reference of that interface will not give any error. In your example your method sysout() is in interface so reference of the interface will not give any error, but for method displayName() interface reference gives an error. For that you have to use your class reference.